# python2 urllib request at hanyu.baidu.com

Tags: python, urllib

I want to make a python script, which is parsing the pronounciation from a chinese character from the site hanyu.baidu.com.

I found a code to make a search at the main site of baidu.com

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-  
import urllib2,urllib,sys,io  

url = "http://www.baidu.com/s" 
search = [('w','吃')]  
getString = url + "?" + urllib.urlencode(search)  
print getString
req = urllib2.Request(getString)  
fd = urllib2.urlopen(req)
```

which is returning the html code of the site

> http://www.baidu.com/s?w=%E5%90%83

This is what I expected. But when I change the url to

```
url = "https://hanyu.baidu.com/s"
```

and the argument to

```
search = [('wd','吃')]
```

I would like to get the result of the site

> https://hanyu.baidu.com/s?wd=%E5%90%83

but instead python returns an page, which says that my I am referring to a page which do not exist (in chinese: 很抱歉，您要访问的页面不存在！)

Why can I open the url in my browser, but not with python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a header to the request, to fake a browser, solved the problem.

```
req.add_header('User-Agent','Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1312.27 Safari/537.17')
```